# Send Data Grid View data to other form in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms `form1` and `form2`. In `form1` I get data from database and fill `DataGridView' with this data.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
var allcustomers = from c in dc.GetTable<Customer>() select new GetCustomers { firstname = c.firstname, lastname = c.lastname, mobile = c.mobile , customerid = c.customerid};
customerBindingSource.DataSource = allcustomers;
dataGridView1.DataSource = customerBindingSource;
```

Then, I create event handler method to get `customerid` by clicking on grid

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int customer_id = list_customers[e.RowIndex].customerid;
            MessageBox.Show((customer_id).ToString());
        }
```

Now, I need to send this customer_id to `form2` to get all information and display.

Any idea how I achieve this? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the customer_id while creating an instance of the second form

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     int customer_id = list_customers[e.RowIndex].customerid;
     SecondForm form2 = new SecondForm(customer_id);
}
```

and in second form you can retrieve this value in constructor,

```
 public Form_2(string custId)
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    var customerId = custId;
 }
```